# Filter DateTime in MS Acess 2010 Database

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have 5070 rows in a Table. But in that many entries are dump entries. I simply want to ignore them. In dump entries I have `1900-01-01 00:00:00` this data in many rows, I want to ignore all the rows which is having above data.

My query looks like this
`Select * from Table where AttendanceDate > #1900-01-01 00:00:00#`

I tried using `CDate(1900-01-01 00:00:00)`, `"#1900-01-01 00:00:00#"`, `<> #1900-01-01 00:00:00#` as well, but nothing helps.

I have gone throuh around 15-20 SO Questions and tried their marked answers but didn't work.

**EDIT**

[image: Sample Image]

I have data like this. I want to filter data that has InTime > 1900-01-01 00:00:00.

The table has only 650 valid entries from 5070 entries. I want to remove all the other extradump entries.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Use Parameters to specify that DateTime value and the problem is gone. `date` is not a good name for a Column (doesn't it look like it could be the name of a data Type?).

Comment: Date literals in Jet/ACE SQL must be in `#MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss#` format, just as they are in VB. Don't use a date literal though. As suggested, ALWAYS use parameters to insert values into SQL code and format issues go away.

Comment: See: [List of reserved words in Access 2002 and in later versions of Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reserved-words)

Comment: @Jimi it was just for example. as i didn't have actual code right here. I have not used `date` name anywhere in y code. Updated the sample code. issue still is there

Comment: That's not the main problem (you could enclose the Column's name in square brackets). The actual problem is not using Parameters (`Parameters.Add()`) to set the value for the comparison. Add a Parameter to the query and specify, e.g., `New DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)` as the value. Let the driver take care of the *internals*.

Comment: It's understood that the Type of the Access Column must be Date (specify `OleDbType.Date` in the Parameter), not a string.

Comment: I am very biginner to MsAccess, could you please write the enire query, so I can get more clarification? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments you have to use the date literals in the format `#MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss#`.

So `"SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE Datum > #1/1/1900 00:00:00#"` should work in your case. Best practise is to use parameters as mentioned in the comments but the previous SQL statement should just work fine for you.

The data type of the field in question shoud be `date/time`.

**PS**: One could use the DateValue function to convert the text in date but this will cause trouble as one can never be sure if the conversion has been successful. IMHO it's best to have the correct data type from the very beginning

`"SELECT * FROM tbl1  WHERE DateValue(Datum) > #1/1/1900 00:00:00#"`

Comment: Nope, Didn't work, I have MS Access 2010. Any syntax difference needed?

Comment: Did you check the data type of the column in question? And if yes, what is the data type? Could you also add some example data to the post. And how do you check _didn't work_? How do you check the result of the SQL statement?

Comment: I forgot about this, I checked and data type is Text, so i need to first convert it into datetime and then compare

Comment: If you want to have a date comaprision you have to convert first.

Comment: how can I convert this in query? could you please help ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the query? It's better to have the data with the correct data type in the database.

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: I also made an edit. But why don't you just change the data type of the column `InTime` to `date/time`?

Comment: I can't, This is the client database so we can not edit it